# Swift configuration throws error "unable to create container" when I click on Dashboard to create container

Tags: storage

Swift configuration throws error "unable to create container"

I get the below error when I try to test from swift Proxy server

Account GET failed: 503 Internal Server Error)

I have 3 proxy nodes already setup. I am following the www.hastexo.com  document

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

@guest

If you are using Ubuntu i would suggest you to follow the official OpenStack Install guide for the same http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_swift.html

This guide is for latest Havana release of OpenStack, hope it helps.